# MS Graph API - Is there a way to get a list of the Booking Businesses that a Staff Member belongs to?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-booking

I'm using MS Graph APIs to manage booking businesses. I follow the documentation provided by Microsoft at this link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/booking-api-overview?view=graph-rest-beta).

My knowledge of Office 365 and its products is basically limited but I'm trying to see if the following is actually possible.

**What I need is:**

To list all the booking business to which a specific staff member has assigned. For example, to have an endpoint like: `/bookingBusinesses/{staff_member_id}/bookings`.

At the moment, there is an API but the other way around, that is, to list the staff members of a specific booking. Here is it: `/bookingBusinesses/{id}/staffMembers`.

**What I have been trying out or digging into:**

I have been Googling around and also digging into Azure AD and Exchange Online to see if there is a workaround for this either using PowerShell or just some other set of APIs. Also trying to get my head around the difference between a `user` and a `booking business` object, since, once you create a new booking it gets added as a new user in Azure AD and Office 365 Admin Center. Anyhow, I couldn't find anything helpful by now.

Honestly, I'm not really optimistic that there is a way to achieve the above but would appreciate helpful thoughts.

Comment: `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/bookingBusinesses/contoso2@jdeva.onmicrosoft.com/staffMembers/fd0b87b0-376b-4e19-9f77-dc50e00307bb` This is the only call I was able to get close enough and if you want to get it this way `/bookingBusinesses/{staff_member_id}/bookings` please raise a feature request in the [Microsoft Grapg Feedback Forum](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests)

Comment: Moving this to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/bookingBusinesses/contoso2@jdeva.onmicrosoft.com/staffMembers/fd0b87b0-376b-4e19-9f77-dc50e00307bb`

This is the only call I was able to get close enough and if you want to get it this way `/bookingBusinesses/{staff_member_id}/bookings`, please raise a feature request in the [Microsoft Graph Feedback Forum](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests).

Comment: that's right I couldn't find anything closer than that API but it's not solving my problem. Because our app may have access to the staff id but has no knowledge of the bookings that associate with that staff, hence, cannot use that endpoint which is utilizing the booking id in the route. It looks like there's no workaround for this yet. I will try to request that as a feature. Thanks.